# TimeArray Dates Issue

Tags: time-series, julia

I would like to ask if anyone knows how to get the Dates from a TimeArray table eg. 36x1 TimeArray{Float64,1} 1980-12-31 to 2015-01-01

1980-12-31 | 0.94

1981-12-31 | 0.37

1982-12-31 | 0.12

1983-12-31 | 0.64

⋮

2012-12-31 | 0.43

2013-12-31 | 0.81

2014-12-31 | 0.88

2015-01-01 | 0.55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read this table into a matrix `x` where the dates are in the first column, then this follows a pattern from the manual http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/dates/ :

`df = Dates.DateFormat("y-m-d");
map(u -> Date(u,df), x[:,1])`

Answer (score 1):

I'm don't know where did those `TimeArray` come from, but because you mentioned that they are of `Float64` type, I think the format might be `UnixDateTime`, so if it's true then you can convert them to julia `DateTime` as follow:
`juliadatetime=[Dates.unix2datetime(t) for t in timearray]`
and then extract what you want
`ymd=[Dates.yearmonthday(t) for t in juliadatetime]`